# Rasterio base object in Python?

Tags: raster, rasterio

I would like to create some simple raster test data using `rasterio` that I can later process. I don't want to write to/read from any files from disk, but instead would like to work from variables/in memory objects. I also don't need to give this raster a projection from the time being.

For `asc` type rasters for example it could be as simple as this:

```
ncols 4
nrows 4
xllcorner 20
yllcorner 8.5
cellsize 0.5
nodata_value -9999
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6
0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7
```

Does `rasterio` support any objects which I can fill out with the above data without worrying about writing to or reading from raster files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `rasterio.io.MemoryFile` might work for your application ([memory file docs](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/memory-files.rst)). For your example, it might look something like:

```
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
from affine import Affine

with MemoryFile() as memfile:
    transform = Affine(0.5, 0, 20, 0, 0.5, 8.5)
    data = np.arange(16).reshape(1, 4, 4) / 10
    meta = {"count": 1, "width": 4, "height": 4, "transform": transform, "nodata": -9999, "dtype": "float64"}
    with memfile.open(driver='GTiff', **meta) as dataset:
        dataset.write(data)
```